# Finding all possible combination of elements across lists of varying length

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

I have n lists, each of which having variable number of elements. I want to find all possible combination of elements across lists.

for eg,

```
list1 = l11, l12  
list2 = l21  
list3 = l31,l32
```

The resulting list should contain

```
    [l11]  
    [l12]  
    [l21]  
    [l31]  
    [l32]  
    [l11, l21]  
    [l12, l21]  
    [l21, l31]  
    [l21, l32]  
    [l11, l31]  
    [l11, l32]
    [l12, l31]
    [l12, l32]  
    [l11, l21, l31]  
    [l11, l21, l32]  
    [l12, l21, l31]  
    [l12, l21, l31]
```

Please provide some insight into solving the problem. I am implementing the solution in java

Comment: how is `listXXX` being stored?

Comment: The n lists are stored in a list, and each list is an ArrayList

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a valid example?

Comment: i guess you need to do some permutation with your array element

Comment: @EvanKnowles Corrected the example

Comment: May I know why it is down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind this recursion is to make all sublists of n-1 lists and then add to every list each element from the first list while maintaining the fact that the element can also be missing from the set (maintaining the full n-1 solution and adding the new possible sets)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Combinations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("l11", "l12");
        List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("l21");
        List<String> l3 = Arrays.asList("l31", "l32");
        List<List<String>> lists = Arrays.asList(l1, l2, l3);
        List<List<String>> allSubsets = allSubsets(lists);
        for (List<String> subset : allSubsets) {
            System.out.println(subset);
        }
    }

    static List<List<String>> allSubsets(List<List<String>> lists) {
        if (lists.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> empty = new ArrayList<>();
            return Arrays.asList(empty);
        }

        List<List<String>> reduced = new ArrayList<>();
        reduced.addAll(lists);
        List<String> list = reduced.remove(0);
        List<List<String>> subsets = allSubsets(reduced);
        List<List<String>> newSubsets = new ArrayList<>(subsets);
        for (List<String> subset : subsets) {
            for (String s : list) {
                List<String> newSubset = new ArrayList<>(subset);
                newSubset.add(s);
                newSubsets.add(newSubset);
            }
        }
        return newSubsets;
    }
}
```